# catch error: Node.js + Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js

please help - can't debug this function, with empty proxy it works, but when i'm using any socks5 proxy (format for ex.: **socks5://username:pass@1.2.3.4:1234**) - fails, but I don't understand where is a problem, how to debug. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks :)

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
"@google-cloud/firestore": "5.0.1",
"make-fetch-happen": "9.1.0"
}
```

*index.js*

```
const fetch = require('make-fetch-happen');
const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");

const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: process.env.FIRESTORE_PROJECT_ID,
  timestampsInSnapshots: true,
});

async function getSegments(appId, apiKey, proxy) {
  const opts = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Basic ${apiKey}`
    }
  }

  if (proxy) {
    opts['proxy'] = proxy
  }

  const resp = await fetch(`https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps/${appId}/segments`, opts)

  const data = await resp.json()
  return data.segments
}

exports.checkProxy = async (req, res) => {

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600')
    res.status(204).send('')
  } else {

    if (!req.body.hasOwnProperty('appIds') || !req.body.appIds || req.body.appIds.length === 0) {
      res.status(403).send('appIds is required')
      return
    }


    let resp = []
    for (const appId of req.body.appIds) {
      const appSnap = await firestore.collection('apps').doc(appId).get()
      if (appSnap.empty) {
        res.status(404).send('app not found')
        return
      }
      const app = appSnap.data()

      try {
        const campaignData = await getSegments(app.appId, app.apiKey, app.proxy)
        resp.push({error: false, app: app.name, appId: app.id})
      } catch (e) {
        resp.push({error: e, app: app.name, appId: app.id})
      }

    }

    res.status(200).send(resp)

  }

}
```

Comment: Fails *how*, exactly? How have you achieved such certainty that the issue you’re encountering is a problem with the code you’ve provided here rather than the proxy server itself? Which proxies are you attempting to use? Does Firebase block traffic from known proxies?

Comment: @esqew Proxies are definitely working, checked. The code does not query as it does with an empty proxy value. If proxy is not specified everything is ok. SOCKS5 proxies with this format socks5://username:pass@1.2.3.4:1234. These are private proxies, I can't post them here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved simply by updating the make-fetch-happen module to version 10.1+. Thanks to the person who gave me a minus without responding - you made the world a better place dude.